# Is tor browser bundle safe for downloading?

Tags: tor

Tor website says "tor browser bundle" is enough if only browsing is required. Is it also equally safe to use for downloading purpose ?

Comment: What they mean is, as long as you only need www access, it'll do fine. Many people use other internet programs, e.g., ssh for remote access. But you'd need a different installation of Tor to get that working, because you _can't_ do it from a browser.

Comment: That is, if you do it from their browser, it should be just as safe as doing something else from their browser.

Comment: Are you saying it is equallly safe for downloading as well ?

Comment: Yes. As long as you use Tor browser to do it. Downloading is still web (www) browsing. It doesn't make a difference whether you read it or store it.

Comment: No problem. I'm going to put it in answer format, though.

Comment: Please don't download excessively large files, though, as this will slow down the whole Tor network & inconvenience the people who really need it (political dissidents in oppressive countries).

Answer (score 4):

Anything you do from a web browser is (technically) web browsing. So, downloading counts as web browsing. What the Tor website (probably) means in this case is that if you want to do something which your browser is *incapable* of doing — such as a remote desktop session, through e.g. rdb, vnc or ssh protocols, you'll have to set up Tor to work more generally, so that programs implementing these protocols can use it.

However, if you go for the Tor browser option, your actions in other programs will **not** be protected. Notably, if you use an alternate browser, it will not be protected.